# Submitting Two forms with one button, with flask request

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am submitting 2 forms with one button using JavaScript. But when I am trying to access it using request.form in flask, it is only showing the 2nd form(the last submitted form). How can I access both forms in the backend? Will I have to use ajax? I am new to JS, flask, HTML. Thanks!

Here's my HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method ="post" id="f1" name = "form1" action="{{url_for('process')}}">
        <input type="text" name = "name">
    </form>
    <form method ="post" id="f2" name="form2" action="{{url_for('process')}}">
        <input type="text" name = "name">
    </form>

    <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="sub()">sub

    </button>
</body>
<script>
    
    function sub(){
        document.getElementById("f1").submit();
        document.getElementById("f2").submit();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Here's my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('forms.html')

@app.route('/processing', methods=['POST',"GET"])
def process():

    print(request.form)   #This only prints ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'name submitted by f2')])
    return "processsed"


if '__main__' == __name__:
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **form data** and send.

**Not tested, if there's any problem please comment.**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method ="post" id="f1" name = "form1" action="{{url_for('process')}}">
        <input type="text" name = "name">
    </form>
    <form method ="post" id="f2" name="form2" action="{{url_for('process')}}">
        <input type="text" name = "name">
    </form>

    <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="sub()">sub

    </button>
</body>
<script>
async function sub() {
    var form = new XMLHttpRequest();
    form.open(document.getElementById("f1").method, document.getElementById("f1").action);
    var p = new Promise(r => {
        form.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (form.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && form.status === 200) r();
        }
    });
    form.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("f1")));
    await p;
    form = new XMLHttpRequest();
    form.open(document.getElementById("f2").method, document.getElementById("f2").action);
    p = new Promise(r => {
        form.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (form.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && form.status === 200) r();
        }
    });
    form.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("f2")));
    await p;
    window.location.reload();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked. But can you tell me what exactly is happening in my scenario, and why it is printing the last form?

Comment: And it just packs two forms of data and sends the first then the second. When two forms is sent, it reloads the page.

Comment: it’s print both data now?

Comment: Yes, actually it is calling processing function each time we send data through XML request, hence it is printing both data now.

Comment: I do not surely know why that's printing last form data.
But I know why It won't print both.
Because when one is submitted, it will reload the page, and the next won't be run.
In this case, I just wait until the first is done and then sent the next.